# Customizing WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am new to `C# WPF`, and customizing `DataGrid` in `C# WPF`, I have created `subclass` a below :-

```
namespace DataGridFiltter
    public class FilteringDataGrid : Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGrid
    {
    .......
    }
}
```

and in `xaml` file i am using this class as below :-

```
<UserControl x:Class="formGroup"
 xmlns:dataGridFiltter="clr-namespace:DataGridFiltter">

<dataGridFiltter:FilteringDataGrid  IsFilteringCaseSensitive="False" x:Name="groupTable"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="16" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding DataCollection, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectionChanged="groupTable_SelectionChanged" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" AlternatingRowBackground="#FFD6D1D1" CanUserAddRows="false" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" IsReadOnly="True" Margin="0,0,-8,0"  >
                <DataGrid.ItemBindingGroup>
                    <BindingGroup/>
                </DataGrid.ItemBindingGroup>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="RecordNumber" Width="100" Visibility="Hidden" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="NAME" Width="200" Binding="{Binding GroupName}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Group Name" Width="144" Binding="{Binding ParentGroupName}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Creation Time" Width="200" Binding="{Binding CreationTime}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Modification Time" Width="200" Binding="{Binding ModificationTIME}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="User" Width="100" Binding="{Binding PeopleName}" />

                </DataGrid.Columns>


            </dataGridFiltter:FilteringDataGrid>
```

As i have used style as below :-

```
<ResourceDictionary
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
   xmlns:dataGridFiltter="clr-namespace:DataGridFiltter">

    <dataGridFiltter:HeaderFilterConverter x:Key="headerConverter"/>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type my:DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type my:DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="ShowFilterControl">
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="filterTextBox" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5000000" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="filterTextBox" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="Transparent"/>
                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5000000" Value="White"/>
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="HideFilterControl">
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="filterTextBox" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.4000000" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="filterTextBox" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.OpacityMask).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="Black"/>
                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.4000000" Value="#00000000"/>
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <my:DataGridHeaderBorder x:Name="dataGridHeaderBorder" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="61" IsClickable="{TemplateBinding CanUserSort}" IsHovered="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}"  IsPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" SeparatorBrush="{TemplateBinding SeparatorBrush}" SeparatorVisibility="{TemplateBinding SeparatorVisibility}" SortDirection="{TemplateBinding SortDirection}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.ColumnSpan="1">
                        <Grid>
                              <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions> 
                            <Grid x:Name="grid" Width="Auto" Grid.Row="0" Height="Auto" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                                <Grid.RenderTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform/>
                                        <SkewTransform/>
                                        <RotateTransform/>
                                        <TranslateTransform/>
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </Grid.RenderTransform>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                             <!--   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions> -->
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" 
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                                    ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" 
                                    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}">
                                <ContentPresenter.Content>
                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource headerConverter}">
                                            <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                                                <Binding ElementName="filterTextBox" Path="Text" />
                                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" Path="Content" />
                                            </MultiBinding.Bindings>
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                </ContentPresenter.Content>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                                <TextBox x:Name="filterTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Right" MinWidth="25" Height="Auto" OpacityMask="Black" Visibility="Visible" Text="" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Grid.ColumnSpan="1"/>

                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </my:DataGridHeaderBorder>                      
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <!--    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="ShowFilterControl_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource ShowFilterControl}"/>
                                <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="HideFilterControl_BeginShowFilterControl"/>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="HideFilterControl_BeginShowFilterControl" Storyboard="{StaticResource HideFilterControl}"/>
                                <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="ShowFilterControl_BeginStoryboard"/>
                            </Trigger.ExitActions> -->
                        </Trigger> 
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I am getting compile time error  (Error :- Event Expected ) for `DataGrid.ItemBindingGroup` ,`DataGrid.Columns` and `DataGridTextColumn`

Can someone please help me what is the right way use above tags as i have created `subclass` of `DataGrid`.

Comment: have you implemented groupTable_SelectionChanged event?

Comment: Yes i have implemented groupTable_SelectionChanged event